# Auto-Clear Text Entry in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to finish a project in my VBA class and am stuck. I've created the program for most of the word search however I cannot get the timerInterval function to work. The challenge and code are below:

3. Create a word search game that allows a user to view a string of characters for a predetermined amount of time (say 5 to 10 seconds). Build a timer to accomplish this. After time is up, hide the string of characters and prompt the user to enter one or more words he saw in the string. For example, the string of characters keoixakaccessqcinmsboxeamlz contains the words access and box. Use the InStr function to determine whether the user’s guess is contained in the word search string.

---

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdShow_Click()
txtOutput.Value = "hello world"
End Sub




Private Sub Form_Load()
txtOutput.Caption = Text
If txtOutput.DefaultValue = Text Then
Me.TimerInterval = 5000
If txtOutput = 0 Then
txtOutput = False


End Sub


Private Sub cmdCheck_click()
Dim guess As Integer
guess = InStr(txtOutput.Value, txtInput.Value)
If guess = 0 Then
    txtResult.Value = "You're terrible at this game"
Else
    txtResult.Value = "Good find!"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the `Sub Form_Timer()` section of code?  That's where the text clearing magic will happen. [check this out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836371.aspx)

Comment: What Jimmy Smith said.
I'll comment on your code though.. So, txtoutput can be a string, a int, and a boolean? That's just asking for trouble.
You should require variable declaration. (VBA Window, Tools>Options). Without variable declaration, a mistype will have you working on 2 different variables, like var1 and va1 and will produce errors hard to track.
You should use End Ifs even for single lines split by _ 
I didn't either, until missing a underscore and messing up my code (and having a hard time finding the error in thousands of lines). The End If makes it way more readable.

Comment: @CyberClaw - your suggestions are not that applicable. He already has Option Explicit at top of code. txtoutput is a control that takes any form of text. If / Endif is a nice suggestion but has nothing to do with his Timer question

Comment: @Matt - are you allowed to use an API call. The Sleep function is very straight forward to declare and to use and makes it very simple to apply a "delay - then do something" in your code

Comment: @dbmitch - my comment refered to things that would make his code not work (even if they were not the source of the question, which like I said, Jimmy identified).

He has the option explicit but he didn't dim the Text var, possibly others. He also had 2 if then, and the commands on another line, without a underscore. nor a end if. 

He assigns what I assume is a string to the txtoutput, compares it to a integer on a if, and then assigns a boolean to the control. He doesn't use Me., a text input box can't have a boolean, but that's a moot point because the if would always be false anyhow...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use API call - I like this method better.

You can just toggle your text control to visible/invisible

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' Simple delay mechanism using Win32 API
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Sub cmdShow_Click()
    txtOutput.Visible = true
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Load()

    txtOutput.Value = "hello world"

    Sleep 5000 ' 5000 milliseconds = 5 second delay
    txtOutput.Visible = false

End Sub


Private Sub cmdCheck_click()

    Dim guess As Integer

    guess = InStr(txtOutput.Value, txtInput.Value)
    If guess = 0 Then
        txtResult.Value = "You're terrible at this game"
    Else
        txtResult.Value = "Good find!"
    End If

End Sub
```